# Selenium Python 3.7 script for toggling radio buttons and downloading citation information giving Google Chrome errors, any solutions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7

Good morning,

I am looking to create a script using Selenium in order to toggle radio buttons, download information using citation.

The following steps are what I have taken:
1)Click the checkbox.
2)Click the export button
3)Open small window
4)Select citation and abstract information button in window
5)Click export
6)Download information

I have a selenium script, but I keep getting errors that have to do with the Google Chrome section. Does here have a similar problem? Thanks.

Tried debugging Selenium script by looking up the google.chrome() issue. Could not find the solution.

#Update

Here is where i'm having the issue with, its with the web.driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
"""May have to use google chrome engine for this"""
#Checkbox setup
#Must specifiy the driver part where Chrome is
#Debug this immediately!
driver = webdriver.Chrome(execeutable_path = r"C:\Users\TheUsersName\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win32\114.0.5735.90.chromedriver.exe")
#Specify the website to download information from
driver.get("https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/9811522/proceeding")
#Working with the radio buttons

#First, inspect the element by right-clicking inspect element(Developers Console)


#Click the checkbox button for citation 

#This can be used to find multiple checkboxes at the same time, just repeat the code below 
driver.find_element_by_id("ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched").click()#First checkbox on the website

#To verify the selection, use the following code
status = driver.find_element_by_id("ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched").is_selected()   
#Will display if its true or not
print(status)
```

The issue i'm having is with the web.driver, apparently the message is the below:

WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'execeutable_path'

#Update
I have corrected the following code above with a new one, but I am getting the following error below with locating Chrome or using the Chrome Binary.

```
#Import modules
from selenium import webdriver
#Use pip install webdriver_manager to install this module below
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
"""May have to use google chrome engine for this. Confirmed"""

#Must specifiy the driver part where Chrome is. This is located in Documents

#ChromeOptions is an instance 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#Debug this immediately!


options.binary_location = r"C:\Users\UserName\Documents\chromedriver.exe"
#Debug this immediately!

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
#setting the binary location of the Chrome Instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH=r"C:\Users\UsersName\Documents\chromedriver.exe")  
#Maximize the window 
#driver.maximize_window()   
#Specify the website to download information from
driver.get('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/9811522/proceeding')

#Checkbox setup

#First, inspect the element by right-clicking inspect element(Developers Console(F12))
#Then, right-click the element and click copy and then copy selector
#Click the checkbox button for citation 

#This can be used to find multiple checkboxes at the same time, just repeat the code below 
driver.find_element_by_id("ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched").click()#First checkbox on the website

#To verify the selection, use the following code
status = webdriver.find_element_by_id("ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched").is_selected()   
#Will display if its true or not
print(status)

What i'm trying to do is find the direct PATH where Selinumn is located. However, when I do this, it comes out as it cannot find the Path or has a binary issue. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: please add the selenium script you've tried along with the error you're getting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Certainly, i'll be updating it with the following above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says,

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'execeutable_path'
```

There is a typo error as the correct one is `executable_path` and not `execeutable_path`.

This way:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\TheUsersName\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win32\114.0.5735.90.chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you Ajeet, I've got the code updated but now it has a different error

Comment: Hello everyone, I have found a solution about this. What I have replaced is options, which is defined by the binary path, and NOT the path of the file. In other words, look for the Binary Path! and executable_path is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. `excutable_path` is no longer a valid method and is deferred. Instead, just using it as `r"TheBinaryLocation.exe"` will solve this problem.